# Trouble modifying content of JQuery drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two `<ul>`s set up and linked for drag / drop via JQuery. I would like to add some text when the field is dropped to the `<li>` that has been dropped.

Here is my code - the drop works fine, but I'm not sure how to modify the text.

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
     }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the [event callback functions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) (click on the "Events" tab) to modify the text. Here I used the `update` event ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/YvyXk/)):

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            // remove other messages
            $('span.message').remove();
            // add message to current item
            ui.item.append('<span class="message"> - dropped!</span>');
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```